# Porting msvc code to Android/ios

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk, porting

I have a pretty large project written in C++ for Windows, with some MSVC-specific fancy things, like `__declspec(property)`, usage of SEH, extra template and macro flexibility, intrinsics and etc.

In a nutshell it consists of various applications and a shared library (lib), which is a pretty large "algorithmic" code. It's written entirely in plain C++ (MSVC's version of it, as I said), not dependent on any 3rd-party, all the code is "hand-made", no stdlib, STL, Boost or etc.

Now this code needs to be ported to mobile platforms, namely Android and iOS.

The code *should* be platform-independent. No explicit dependence on OS, besides the very basic things, like heap memory allocation. It does depend on some Windows-specific things: SEH, TLS, but those are the things I can sacrifice, if they can't be replaced.

And I'm thinking about how to deal with it. Cleaning the whole code from MSVC-specific stuff is possible, but not convenient. I'd prefer to keep them, and definitely I don't want to keep several codebases for different platforms.

So, what are the options at my disposal?
As I understood, there are C++ compilers for Android (part of NDK), but they are probably standard C++ compliant. Anyway, iOS development is based on Objective-C, which is a superset of plain C.

This led me to an idea to "compile" the existing MSVC-specific C++ code into a plain C. There is an option in MSVC compiler to generate "listing" files, containing the assembler code. I guess if there's an option to create appropriate listings containing C-code. Or alternatively MSVC-compliant 3rd party C++ -> C converters.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SEH is awesome. But it *really* hurts portability. The GCC folks rejected try/except/finally as an extension for C in their compilers. I don't recall why, though.

Comment: FWIW, even if iOS development is based on Objective-C, you still can use portable C++ just fine there, and you can write Objective-C++ to integrate it (basically files which can contain both Objective C and C++ syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC++ to C compilers come in the "if you have to ask, you can't afford it"  category. Just too small a market.

A more realistic chance would be to wait what Microsoft is doing. They're seriously looking into targeting additional mobile platforms with MSVC 2015.

TLS is probably the easiest, as that is standard C++ (`thread_local`). SEH should be mapped to regular C++ exception handling, which means you need to trap pointer bugs before they happen. MSVC isn't exactly known for *extra* template flexibility, it's in fact rather inflexible. x86 intrinsics obviously are right out on ARM.

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely going to play with MSVC2015, it just sounds too good to be true. About the platform-dependend things (SEH, TLS, intrinsics) - it's ok, I'll handle this myself, I also don't expect an automatic tool to do this instead of me.

Answer (score 3):

> So, what are the options at my disposal?

Write portable C or C++ code.

I've got C and C++ libraries that run on Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Windows, BSD, OS X and Linux. The library is written once and it runs everywhere.

While the "core library" is portable C/C++, the next layer up is not. That's where the libraries integrate with the platform. For example, the iOS test suite driver has a Cocoa/CocoaTouch UI on Apple platforms, and an MFC test suite drive on Windows and Windows Mobile. And the test suite drivers on Linux are command line because I don't waste time with GTK or Qt.

The routines to seed the random number generators are platform specific. I consider them a core function, so its in the core library and guarded by platform specific `#defines`.

*Don't* make the mistake of re-implementing your core library on every platform it runs on. That means you will need 4x to 8x the development cycles to duplicate the code and behavior. And there will always be small, hidden behavioral bugs that you waste countless hours tracking down.

---

> And I'm thinking about how to deal with it. Cleaning the whole code from MSVC-specific stuff is possible, but not convenient.

Yes, do this. Pay the tax once and enjoy the benefits for the remainder of the code's life.

---

> This led me to an idea to "compile" the existing MSVC-specific C++ code into a plain C.

No, I would not do this. Remove the platform specific stuff from the core library. Make the core library portable.